# changing the position of random number of divs when the mouse pointer enters the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do not know how to create div in a loop in jquery, and also how to change the position of them using "mouseover" function. this is my code that creates div elements but the position of the elements did not change. Can anyone help me to correct my code?

```js
var r, g, b, counter, i;
//generate random number between 20 and number.
function generateRandomNumber(number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number - 20)) + 20;
}
// maximum number of random elements is 30.
counter = generateRandomNumber(30);
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  var div = $("<div/>");
  div.id = "randomlyPlaced" + i;
  //random style for the elements
  r = generateRandomNumber(255);
  g = generateRandomNumber(255);
  b = generateRandomNumber(255);
  $(div).css({
    position: "absolute",
    background: "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")",
    height: generateRandomNumber(200) + "px",
    width: generateRandomNumber(400) + "px",
    top: generateRandomNumber(500) + "px",
    left: generateRandomNumber(1000) + "px"
  });
  //append the elements to body.
  $('body').append(div);
  //change the position of the element.
  $("#" + div.id).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: generateRandomNumber(500) + "px",
      left: generateRandomNumber(1000)
    }, 500, "linear");
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Randomly Placed Animated rectangles</title>
</head>

<body style="width: 80%; height: 80%; background-color :rgb(164, 173, 
    226); position:relative;">
  <div id='+div.id+'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think these documents will be useful
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
I can tell you with samples if it won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `div` object itself instead of `"#"+div.id` the reason is this id works when element is loaded in DOM, while thats not true in case you as you are generating div dynamically.

```
$(div).mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
         top: generateRandomNumber(500) + "px", 
         left:generateRandomNumber(1000)
      },500,"linear");
});
```

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/t5w6cm9x/

Comment: yeah you're right, thank you so much for your help :-)